# Como puedo modificar este método para que no distinga en Mayúsculas y minúsculas?

Tags: android

Tengo un listview que filtro con addTextChangedListener pero distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas con lo que el filtro se deja atrás palabras que me gustaría que incluyese. ¿Que código debería añadir para eso? Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

```
          public class codificado_trafico extends AppCompatActivity implements Filter.FilterListener{

    private String name;        // spinner
    private int categoryID;     // spinner
    ListView lvElements;
    TextView tvTotals;
    EditText etSearch;
    String urlname;
    StringFilterCountArrayAdapter adapter;
    Filter.FilterListener listener;
   private Spinner mySpinner;
    static String[] tokens;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.codificado_trafico );
    // Arreglo de codigos de proyecto.

     final String [] materia = {"Todas", "Adelantamiento", "Señalización", "Otros"};

    String tokens[] = {
            "Comportarse indebidamente en la circulación causando peligro a las personas",
            "Comportarse indebidamente en la circulación entorpeciendo la misma, causando perjuicios y molestias innecesarias a las personas o daños a los bienes",
            "Conducir de forma temeraria",
            "Conducir sin la diligencia, precaución y no distracción necesarios para evitar todo daño propio o ajeno",
            "Conducir de forma negligente creando una situación de riesgo o peligro para sí mismo, los demás ocupantes del vehículo o al resto de usuarios de la vía",
            "Arrojar sobre la vía objetos o materias que hagan peligrosa la libre circulación, parada o estacionamiento o deteriorar aquella o sus instalaciones",
            "Depositar o abandonar sobre la vía objetos o materias que puedan entorpecer la libre circulación, parada o estacionamiento",
            "Realizar actuaciones, rodajes, encuestas o ensayos, que aunque sean con carácter provisional o temporal, Puedan entorpecer la  circulación",
            "No hacer desaparecer lo antes posible un obstáculo o peligro en la vía por quien lo ha creado",
            "No adoptar las medidas necesarias para advertir a los demás usuarios la existencia de un obstáculo o peligro creado en la vía por el propio denunciado",  //10

    };




    final String [][] datos = {

            {"RGCir\nLSV", "2\n10","1","5D","0","Leve","Conductor\nUsuario","100\n50","Comportarse indebidamente en la circulación causando peligro a las personas. (deberá indicarse detalladamente el comportamiento y/o el Tipo de peligro causado).",""},
            {"RGCir\nLSV", "2\n10","1","5E","0","Leve","Conductor\nUsuario","80\n40","Comportarse indebidamente en la circulación entorpeciendo la misma, causando perjuicios y molestias innecesarias a las personas o daños a los bienes. (deberá indicarse detalladamente el comportamiento y/o el tipo de perjuicio, molestia o daño causados).",""},
            {"RGCir\nLSV", "3\n10","1\n2","5A","6","Muy Grave","Conductor","500\n250","Conducir de forma temeraria. (describir con detalle la conducta merecedora del calificativo de temeraria).","Habrá que tener en cuenta, a efectos de traslado al Ministerio Fiscal, los casos en los que los hechos pudieran ser constitutivos de delito previsto en el art. 380 del Código Penal"},
            {"RGCir\nLSV", "3\n10","1\n2","5C","0","Grave","Conductor","200\n100","Conducir sin la diligencia ,precaución y no distracción necesarios para evitar todo daño propio o ajeno (deberá Detallarse la conducta).",""},
            {"RGCir\nLSV", "3\n10","1\n2","5D","0","Grave","Conductor","200\n100","Conducir de forma negligente creando una situación de riesgo o peligro para sí mismo, los demás ocupantes del vehículo o al resto de usuarios de la vía. (deberá detallarse, de modo sucinto y claro, la conducta y el riesgo o peligro que implica).",": En el caso de que no quedase suficientemente justificada la creación de la situación de riesgo o peligro, se optará por dar de alta el procedimiento incoado mediante el precepto CIR 3-1- 5C"},
            {"RGCir\nLSV", "4\n12","2\n2","5A","4","Grave","Conductor","200\n100","Arrojar sobre la vía objetos o materias que hagan peligrosa la libre circulación, parada o estacionamiento o deteriorar aquella o sus instalaciones (deberá indicarse el objeto o materia que cause el Peligro o deterioro).","Habrá que tener en cuenta, a efectos de traslado al Ministerio Fiscal, los casos en los que los hechos pudieran ser constitutivos de delito previsto en el art. 385 del Código Penal"},
            {"RGCir\nLSV", "4\n12","2\n2","5B","0","Leve","Conductor\nUsuario","80\n40","Depositar o abandonar sobre la vía objetos o materias que puedan entorpecer la libre circulación, parada o estacionamiento (deberá indicarse el objeto o materia que cause el entorpecimiento)","Habrá que tener en cuenta, a efectos de traslado al Ministerio Fiscal, los casos en los que los hechos pudieran ser constitutivos de delito previsto en el art. 385 del Código Penal"},
            {"RGCir\nLSV", "4\n12","3\n2","5B","0","Leve","Autor","80\n40","Realizar actuaciones, rodajes, encuestas o ensayos, que aunque sean con carácter provisional o temporal, Puedan entorpecer la  circulación (detallar los hechos).",""},
            {"RGCir\nLSV", "5\n12","1\n3","5A","0","Leve","Conductor\nUsuario","80\n40","No hacer desaparecer lo antes posible un obstáculo o peligro en la vía por quien lo ha creado  (deberá indicarse el obstáculo o peligro existente)","Habrá que tener en cuenta, a efectos de traslado al Ministerio Fiscal, los casos en los que los hechos pudieran ser constitutivos de delito previsto en el art. 385 del Código Penal"},
            {"RGCir\nLSV", "5\n12","1\n3","5B","0","Leve","Conductor\nUsuario","80\n40","No adoptar las medidas necesarias para advertir a los demás usuarios la existencia de un obstáculo o peligro creado en la vía por el propio denunciado",""}, //10


    };
    // Spinner
    Spinner mySpinner =(Spinner)findViewById ( R.id.spinner );

    final List materias = new ArrayList (  );
    materias.add ( "Totas" );
    materias.add ( "Cinturón" );

    ArrayAdapter spinadapter = new ArrayAdapter ( this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, materias );
    mySpinner.setAdapter ( spinadapter );

    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener ( new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener () {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (parent.getItemAtPosition ( position ).equals ( "Cinturón" )){

                Intent i=new Intent(codificado_trafico.this, CtCinturon.class );
                startActivity(i);}


        }




        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        } ;


    } );

    tvTotals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotals);


    etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);

    //Listview
    lvElements = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvElements);
    List data = new ArrayList ();
    data.addAll(Arrays.asList(tokens));
    adapter = new StringFilterCountArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.itam_list_trafico, R.id.codigo_token,data );

    lvElements.setAdapter(adapter);
    onFilterComplete(data.size()); //El parámetro no se usa pero ya que estamos pasémoslo bien



    lvElements.setOnItemClickListener ( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String Seleccion= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            int control =0;
            if (Seleccion.equals("Comportarse indebidamente en la circulación causando peligro a las personas"))  { control=0;     }
            else if(Seleccion.equals("Comportarse indebidamente en la circulación entorpeciendo la misma, causando perjuicios y molestias innecesarias a las personas o daños a los bienes")) {control=1;}
            else if(Seleccion.equals("Conducir de forma temeraria")){control=2;}
            else if(Seleccion.equals("Conducir sin la diligencia, precaución y no distracción necesarios para evitar todo daño propio o ajeno")){control=3;}
            else if(Seleccion.equals("Conducir de forma negligente creando una situación de riesgo o peligro para sí mismo, los demás ocupantes del vehículo o al resto de usuarios de la vía"))  {control=4;}
            else if(Seleccion.equals("Arrojar sobre la vía objetos o materias que hagan peligrosa la libre circulación, parada o estacionamiento o deteriorar aquella o sus instalaciones")){control=5;}
            else if(Seleccion.equals("Depositar o abandonar sobre la vía objetos o materias que puedan entorpecer la libre circulación, parada o estacionamiento")){control=6;}
            else if(Seleccion.equals("Realizar actuaciones, rodajes, encuestas o ensayos, que aunque sean con carácter provisional o temporal, Puedan entorpecer la  circulación")) {control=7;}
            else if(Seleccion.equals("No hacer desaparecer lo antes posible un obstáculo o peligro en la vía por quien lo ha creado")) {control=8;}
            else if(Seleccion.equals("No adoptar las medidas necesarias para advertir a los demás usuarios la existencia de un obstáculo o peligro creado en la vía por el propio denunciado")) {control=9;}
            else if(Seleccion.equals("No señalizar de forma eficaz (tanto de dia como de noche) un obstaculo o peligro en la vía por quien lo ha creado"))    {control=10;}

            {String Seleccion_Mesoamerica = (String)lvElements.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent visorDetalles = new Intent ( view.getContext (), detalles_trafico.class );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "NORMA", datos[control][0] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "ARTICULO", datos[control][1] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "APARTADO", datos[control][2] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "OPCION", datos[control][3] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "PUNTOS", datos[control][4] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "CALIFICACION", datos[control][5] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "RESPONSABLE", datos[control][6] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "CUANTIA", datos[control][7] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "DESCRIPCION", datos[control][8] );
                visorDetalles.putExtra ( "COMENTARIOS", datos[control][9] );
                startActivity ( visorDetalles );}




        }




    });


    /* Activando el filtro de busqueda */
    etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher () {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            codificado_trafico.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,   int arg3) { }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {  }  });

    // MOSTRANDO BOTON VOLVER
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar ();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled ( true );

} // Fin metodo onCreate


// Petodo del filtro para contar elementos.
@Override
public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
    String totalsText = String.format("%d/%d", adapter.getFilteredCount(), adapter.getTotalCount());
    tvTotals.setText(totalsText);

} // Fin metodo onFilterComplete
```

}

Comment: Mira el código de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22342298/255257) (en inglés). Allí se escribe una clase que extiende `filter` para realizar un filtrado que no distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Te puedes ubicar en la línea que inicia con `private class ValueFilter extends Filter`.

Comment: puedes poner el código del filtrado?

Comment: para que te sea mas facil puedes utilizar Str.toUpperCase() a la hora de comparar... asi siempre compara mayusculas y no importa si se envia en minuscula o mayuscula

Comment: Julian: te refieres al método "StringFilterCountArrayAdapter"

Comment: Bryro: donde coloco ese método?